# Count number of items per ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as below

**INPUT**

```
ID    ITEM
1     Apple
1     Banana
1     Orange
2     Pear
3     Apple
3     Pear
```

I want to count the items per id, such as

**OUTPUT**

```
ID    ITEM    ITEMS_PER_ID
1     Apple    3
1     Banana   3
1     Orange   3
2     Pear     1
3     Apple    2
3     Pear     2
```

Using count with group by does not achieve the desire result. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT()`:

```
select *, count(item) over(partition by id) as items_per_id from t
```

Result:

```
id  item    items_per_id
--  ------  ------------
1   Apple              3
1   Banana             3
1   Orange             3
2   Pear               1
3   Apple              2
3   Pear               2
```

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  item varchar(10)
);

insert into t (id, item) values 
  (1, 'Apple'),
  (1, 'Banana'),
  (1, 'Orange'),
  (2, 'Pear'),
  (3, 'Apple'),
  (3, 'Pear');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the totals

```
select a.ID,    ITEM,    ITEMS_PER_ID

from tbl a
inner join
(
  select ID, count(distinct ITEM) as ITEMS_PER_ID
  from tbl group by ID
)b on a.ID = b.ID
```